# keep database in memory, even if client script is disconnected

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, memory

I need to preprocess some statistics data before writing it to the main database. My php-cli script retrieves data every 10 minutes and should store it somewhere. Every hour all saved data are preprocessed again and then writted to the main db.

I thought that sqlite should be nice solution if I would keep it in memory. I have not very big amounts of data (I am able to keep it in my RAM).

Actually, I am new to sqlite (previously I was working only with mySQL).
I found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) that I can use `:memory:` instead of file name to work with memory only. But after client is disconnected database is destroyed, and if I will try to connect again to `:memory:` from my script - it will be different (new, empty) database.

Is it right? If it is, how can I work with same database using different php script calls, if sqlite is stored in memory?

P.S. perhaps it is a solution to put sqlite file to some "magic" directory? (I am using linux)

Comment: Very probably a DBMS like MariaDB (MySQL), PostgresQL, MongoDB .... will keep in practice a small database in memory by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, linux is pretty smart about using a filesystem cache. Thus, reading data from a disk is often surprisingly fast, and you should measure if the performance gain is worth it.

If you want to go ahead, one method you might consider is using a ramdisk. Linux provides a way to create a filesystem in memory, and you can place your sqlite file in there.

```
# mkdir -i /mnt/ram
# mount -t ramfs -o size=20m ramfs /mnt/ram
# touch mydb.sql
# chown apache:apache mydb.sql
```

... or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite database created in `:memory:` is automatically destroyed when you disconnect from database handle or exit/terminate process that what using it.

If you want to have multiple PHP sessions to have access to database, you *cannot* use `:memory:`. If you don't have big amounts of data, you should store your intermediate results in helper tables in some persistent database - MySQL or SQLite using real file on disk.